# Uncaught TypeError ("no access") issue with jquery depending on browser navigation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've tried to research this, but I'm totally stumped. I think this may have something to do with the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), but I can't figure out how it relates to my code.

I have a php site running jquery and bootstrap, which renders a dynamic web form at mysite/build.php. The head containing my script calls is shown below:

```
<head>
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">        
    
    <!-- Bootstrap Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <!-- app CSS -->
    <link href="/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    
    <!-- Are-You-Sure dirty form checker -->
    <script src="/js/are-you-sure.js"></script>
    
    <!-- app JavaScript -->
    <script src="/js/build-edit-scripts.js"></script>
    
    <!-- obtain sheet data for edit mode -->
    <?php if (isset($items)): ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var items = <?php echo json_encode($items) ?>; 
            var sheetinfo = <?php echo json_encode($sheetinfo) ?>;
            var slug = <?php echo json_encode($slug) ?>;
        </script>
    <?php endif ?>
    
    <!-- obtain single block and bullet elements for js -->
    <script> var blockHTML = <?php echo json_encode($blockhtml) ?>; var bulletHTML = <?php echo json_encode($bullethtml) ?>;</script>
    
    <title><?= (isset($sheetinfo)) ? "Edit: ".htmlspecialchars($sheetinfo['name']) : "Shopping List Generator"; ?></title>
    
</head>
```

Then the beginning of my custom javascript (build-edit-scripts.js) is shown below

```
//execute when DOM fully loaded 
$(function() {

// enable areYouSure plugin to detect dirty form changes
$('#myform').areYouSure();

// mark form as dirty any time any text input changes
$(document).on('change', 'input:text', function() {
    $('#myform').addClass('dirty');
});

    // create empty array for existing slugs
    var slugs = [];
    
    // initiate ajax request to get dir listing of existing sheets
    $.ajax({

        url: "json-io.php",
     
        data: {
            purpose: "sheetlist"
        },

        type: "POST",

        dataType : "json"
    })

    // if successful
    .done(function(dirjson) {
            slugs = dirjson;
          })

    // if failure
    .fail(function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
            alert( "Server Error" );
            console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
            console.log( "Status: " + status );
            console.dir( xhr );
    });         

    // give focus to title field
    $("#title").focus();
```

When I initially load build.php, or hard refresh it, I have no problems. However, whenever I navigate away to an outside site, and then **hit the back navigation and return to build.php**, I receive the following console error:

> Uncaught TypeError: no access (@ jquery-3.1.0.min.js:2)

followed by issues related to improper jquery loading

> Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery (@ bootstrap.min.js:6)
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined (@ are-you-sure.js:192)
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined (@ build-edit-scripts.js:12)

From here, none of the rest of my JS works. I originally thought this might be due to a problem with my ajax request, but even when I remove the ajax request entirely, the issue persists. Any insight would be greatly appreciated, since I can't seem to target where the problem is occurring. Thanks.

Comment: I just experienced this issue today for the first time. I tested in Firefox and Safari and saw no issues. Quitting and re-opening Chrome caused the issue to stop occurring. (I have a tendency to keep my browser open for days at a time.)

Answer (score 10):

Came across this because I have (or had) the same the error in Chrome when navigating back using the back button from a link. As soon as the page loads after navigating and any script tries to access the window object, this error occurs.

This page was one of only 2 references to this error message ( "Uncaught TypeError: no access" ) I can find anywhere on the web - the other is a Chrome bug report that was supposedly fixed a year ago. Don't think it has anything to do with jQuery (ours is pure javascript), but have no idea what causes it or what it means, it seems like a very obscure error. After restarting the browser this error was no longer reproducible, but it has been seen more than once. It occurs as soon as the script code tries to read any window property of the window object. Posting this in case anyone has clue as to what this error means and what could possibly cause it.

Comment: Thanks for the input - you're right on. Since posting this question, it has been the case for me as well that the error is not reliably reproducible. I noticed the error disappeared without my changing anything, and since then it popped up briefly once, but has not been a problem since.

Comment: Hi, thought I'd say I'm seeing this too interestingly in a very specific circumstance. I have a simply jQuery script that writes a href links dynamically on a page, if one of those is "http://google.com" then after the user clicks the link and navigates to google then clicks back in Chrome (works fine in Edge) this error occurs and all JavaScript on the page fails (window object == null). Interestingly it DOESNT happen with other links like http://microsoft.com (and a few others I've tried). So sounds like a bug in Chrome to do with the way some sites work.

Comment: can confirm... this is still a bug in Chrome, but don't know if there's an open bug report for it

Comment: Thank you! I'd been finding the same. I'm loading GPT (ads) and getting the `no access` error from `pubads_impl.js`, but only when navigating away (to Google.com, didn't try other sites) and back. I thought it might be trying to use `document.write`. Closing/opening chrome fixed it (for now)

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is that your CORS aren't configured properly, although it seems fine, or your document isn't fully loaded when you try to access jQuery, which it appears like your code should be loading fine.

Are you sure you need the `integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s=" crossorigin="anonymous"` tags on the end of your script inclusions? These might not be the proper parameters and could be causing some conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening to me somewhat often on YouTube. This makes me think it's a Chrome bug, as I'm rather sure they'd have all of the things like CORS configured correctly.

Reloading the page usually fixes it, but it's happening fairly often (my browser has been open for a few days now.) As others have said, hitting the back button often causes it but the way YouTube loads its pages I get this even just clicking out of a video to go back to the YouTube home page.

My suggestion is to raise the bug again, as it's happening on Google's own websites now.

Here's the error from the Chrome console - I rather think this is happening before the page scripts are running:

```
(unknown) Uncaught TypeError: no access       (unknown)
    at <anonymous>:10:29
    at <anonymous>:58:5
(index):1 Uncaught TypeError: no access       (index.js:1)
    at (index):1
(index):11 Uncaught TypeError: no access
    at Object.k [as runBeforeBodyIsReady] ((index):11)
    at (index):16
scheduler.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: no access
    at scheduler.js:10
    at scheduler.js:40
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: How so? My suggestion is that it's still an active bug. I'm getting it on sites I'm not developing, major ones such as YouTube. I wanted to post my response as a comment, but I do not have sufficient points.

Comment: To add some more context, when this happens the window object seems to be broken. Entering `window` in the console works, but it has no properties. Trying to access any member of `window`, even `window.xyz` results in the **uncaught TypeError: no access**.
I posit this is a Chrome bug. Care to weigh in on your downvote?